# Show image overlay on Map QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am new to QML. I checked Map QML type to find out how can I show a georeferenced image on map but could not find any solutions. Is it even possible? I found Quickmapcontrols but I'm not sure if it is possible to use them.

Can someone please give me some hints about this problem?

Comment: [QMap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html) is different to [Map QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html)

Comment: @eyllanesc yes I edited the question, I mean Map QML

Comment: Do you want to show a marker that shows an image?

Comment: @eyllanesc in fact I want to show a geotiff image

Comment: see this: https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/latest/qml/api-reference/qml-esri-arcgisruntime-raster.html

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks but I can not use Esri products as they are not open source (as far as I know)  I am just able to use QML Qlocation map

Comment: You need use something to read the geotiff metadata and the image, e.g. GDAL and after that you can create a `MapQuickItem` and display the image on the map. See this maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807705/create-an-rbg-color-qimage-from-a-gdaldataset

Comment: @smaryus hi, thnaks. the problem was with the fact that `mapquickitem` gets a point as location not an extent